# Retrofit 2 example tutorial but GsonConverterFactory display error "Cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, android-library, okhttp

I'm trying to follow Retrofit's 2 [tutorial,](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client/) but on this part of the code there is a `GsonConverterFactory` that displays error `Cannot resolve symbol`:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://your.api-base.url";

    private static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    //THIS IS THE LINE WITH ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Previously I added in my gradle.build, I'm not sure if I should add GSON since they say Retrofit 1.9 has it but nothing is mentioned about Retrofit 2:

```
dependencies {  
    // Retrofit & OkHttp
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
}
```

Comment: You cannot use GsonConverterFactory in Retrofit 2, since it is only applicable to Retrofit 1

Comment: I am following this tutorial : http://wiki.workassis.com/android-retrofit-2-1-http-client/

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/41015925/3470479

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**EDIT**

retrofit 2 is now stable. Use

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

in your `build.gradle` dependency section

***old answer***

with Retrofit 2.0 you have to declare in your build.gradle the convert factory you want to use. Add

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

to your gradle and sync it again

Answer (score 11):

From [another article](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-upgrade-guide-from-1-9/) on that site

> **Retrofit 2 doesn’t ship with Gson by default.** Before, you didn’t need to worry about any integrated converter and you could use Gson out of the box. This library change affects your app and you need to import a converter as a sibling package as well. We’ll touch the converter later within this post and show you how to config the Gson or any other response converter for your app.

Thus, add this to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

New version is now available

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason to such behavior in my case was typo in `build.gradle` dependency. 
After `beta4` release I've updated from:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

to

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

and the right dependency was

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

Also worth notice, that **beta4 - retrofit won't work with beta2 - gson**!

Answer (score 4):

As Updated Retrofit Library with New Version

With

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
```

You must have to include dependency of:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used

```
RestService restService=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.Base_URl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())
                    .build().create(RestService.class);
```

And dependencies:

```
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
        // RxJava adapter for retrofit
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
        // RxJava libraries
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.10'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'

use retrofit and gson of the same version code
```

Comment: I think compile is deprecated; should replace with implementation

Answer (score 2):

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

As gson is by-default not available with retrofit, use both retrofit and converter-gson dependencies as:

```
def retrofitVersion = "2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
```

You can find the latest version of retrofit [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit) and gson converter [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson)

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing the GsonConverterFactory . GsonConverterFactory is a used for converting JSON responses from the server into Kotlin or Java objects.

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
```

please add this dependency into your build.gradle(app) .