# GSON custom field parsing with Retrofit2 - Android

Tags: android, json, gson

I have this JSON :

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "date": "2016-01-01"
    },
    "first": "05:33",
    "second": "05:50",
    "third": "07:22"
}
```

Usually we do something like this to parse this json using Gson retrofit parser :

```
Class MyObject {
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    Attribues attributes;
    @SerializedName("first")
    String first;
    @SerializedName("second")
    String second;
    @SerializedName("third")
    String third;
}
```

And

```
Class Attributes {
    @SerializedName("date")
    String date;
}
```

But what I want to do is this:

```
Class MyObject {
    // I want date to be here and ignoring the attributes key <--- 
    String date;
    @SerializedName("first")
    String first;
    @SerializedName("second")
    String second;
    @SerializedName("third")
    String third;
}
```

How can we do this ?

Comment: I think you should do custom converter. Take a look on this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502079/custom-converter-for-retrofit-2

Comment: but i use a library for android called retrofit and they use their converter, if it can be possible in a way that i use their converter and make it as for second solution.

Comment: Yes, link which I gave you is exactly about retrofit2 custom json converter

Answer (score 2):

90% of questions about GSon has the same answer: use a [custom TypeAdapter](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)

Comment: So, if my class has 10+ fields and only one field is problematic, I cannot just tell GSon how to convert that specific field, but have to write an entire custom adapter for my class? My class has a Time field whose type is `DateTime` in C# but `Date` in Java. Newtonsoft.Json serialised it like '2016-11-05T14:23:00', but GSon throwed an exception (No time zone indicator) for that field while deserialising the object.

Comment: just provide your type adapter for a Date