# How provide Custom Converter for Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I know a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502079/custom-converter-for-retrofit-2) have been asked and answered, but my case is a little different.

I have an **encrypted** response which when decrypted makes an `XML` response (decryption is implemented). So I can't use `SimpleXmlConverterFactory`. Since with `Retrofit` I don't have access to the body of the Response I can't decrypt it. However If I can somehow access the response body (with in the converter factory perhaps or by some other means) and change it to the decrypted `XML` I can continue using Retrofit.

So I did my research; while I don't understand `Converter.Factory` much I think there might be a way to achieve my goal by overriding either this or `SimpleXmlConverterFactory`. But I can't do that without source code.

So here's my question: can I access and decrypt the response `String` by any means using Retrofit?

If however I can manage that then I can keep using Retrofit otherwise I'll have to switch to `HttpURLConnection`. Which I don't want to do because this encrypted response is for a single call-response.

Answer (score 0):

You may write custom converter using sources of [SimpleXmlConverter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/simplexml/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/simplexml).
You should add decryption/encryption in `convert` methods of `RequestBodyConverter` and `ResponseBodyConverter`

Comment: Yes I already got to that part, trouble is I don't understand *how* the `serializer` works. And serializer takes a reader as an input parameter from `ResponseBody`. I can't simple pass a String. I thought about creating a temporary file and providing stream for that but haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: @Abbas Take bytestream or charstream from `ResponseBody`, decrypt.
You may send to serializer String or InputStream, see http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Serializer.html

Comment: You don't understand I have already decrypted the response however I couldn't change the value in the source (cache presumably in this case). But I did find a method within `org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer` where source as a `String` is taken. So I'm all set. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Serializer.html#read(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)