# RxJava - Extension Function for Subscribe

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-extension

I'm trying to use RxJava / Retrofit, and I want to write an extension function to wrap some logic with the network result.

I have a class, `NetworkConsumer` that extends `Consumer`.

```
abstract class NetworkConsumer<T> : Consumer<NetworkResponse<T>> {

    override fun accept(response: NetworkResponse<T>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            onSuccess(response.data)
        } else {
            onFailure()
        }
    }

    // other functions such as onSuccess and onFailure
}
```

I want to create an extension function to allow me to use the Lambda syntax like you can do with normal `Consumers`.

```
service.login(email, password)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            result -> 
                // result is the correct object
        }, {
           // handle the error
        })
```

However, if I want to use my `NetworkConsumer`, I must do:

```
.subscribe(object : NetworkConsumer<LoginResponse>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(response: LoginResponse) {
                        // ...
```

So I'm trying to write an extension function, like:

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.subscribe(onNext: NetworkConsumer<in T>, onError: Consumer<in Throwable>): Disposable {
    return subscribe(onNext, onError, Functions.EMPTY_ACTION, Functions.emptyConsumer<Any>())
}
```

But it doesn't compile, the error is:

```
> Type mismatch. 

> Required: Consumer<in T!>! 

> Found: NetworkConsumer<in T>
```

Comment: Have you considered using RxKotlin (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin) which is basically just a collection of Kotlin extension methods for RxJava? You may also just look at their code how the subscriber extensions are implemented https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin/blob/2.x/src/main/kotlin/io/reactivex/rxkotlin/subscribers.kt

Comment: I've been looking into that, and tried a few things, and while I was able to get their code to work for the extension functions, I'm still unsure how to modify it to get me the result back how I want it. I don't understand how to use my `NetworkConsumer` in that context, and allow me to route all errors to the onError consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it is because your `NetworkConsumer` class extends with `NetworkResponse<T>` generic type.

Your extension function works with `Observable<T>` object which expects `Consumer<T>` object for subscribe. When you put your `NetworkConsumer` for subscribing it equals to `Consumer<NetworkResponse<T>>` object.

So here is mismatch: `Consumer<T>` against `Consumer<NetworkResponse<T>>`. You should rewrite your class like `NetworkConsumer<T> : Consumer<T>`.

**Added**

If it is important to use only `NetworkResponse` types for consumer, you can do following:

1) Add extending statement of generic type for your `NetworkConsumer` class.

```
abstract class NetworkConsumer<T : NetworkResponse<TResponce>, TResponce> : Consumer<T> {...
```

Here `T` - type to "put" inside parent `Consumer` class, that can be only `NetworkResponse`. And `TResponce` - type of real responce that should be placed in `NetworkResponse`.

2) Make all of your `retrofit` api interface methods as returning `NetworkResponse<...>` object. After this there should not be any compile errors, but it is not enough - `retrofit` doesn't know how to create objects of your `NetworkResponse` class.

3) I think this moment would be most difficult. You need to create [your own converter factory](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Converter.Factory.html) to say `retrofit` how to create responces objects for you. May be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502079/custom-converter-for-retrofit-2) can help, or you can find some similar solutions at google.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot. I need to wrap `NetworkResponse` because all the responses from the server return a 200, but contain a status themselves. So I'm wrapping that logic so I can easily get the actual status and payload.

Comment: @Advice-Dog I added solution with converter factory to my answer. Wish it can help you.