# Retrofit + Gson: calculate a field dynamically or call constructor

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, okhttp

When a response comes with Retrofit mapped to a model with Gson I like to calculate a field instead if setting the received value.

When the response comes back for an accessToken, it looks like this:

```
public class UserTokenResponse {
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    private String accessToken;          //v^1.1#i^1#r...
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    @Expose
    private long accessTokenExpiresIn;   //7200
    //Constructor... setter ... getter
}
```

The problem here is the field accessTokenExpiresIn 7200. I like to have it calculated like this:

```
public UserTokenResponse (...) {        //Constructor
    this.accessTokenExpiresIn = System.currentTimeMillis() + 
    (accessTokenExpiresIn * 1000L);
}
```

So that it will become a Unix timestamp with the actual expires millisecond. But as the constructor is not called the field will be 7200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to this is probably to use Gson's [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) on the field and to specify a type adapter which performs this calculation. The adapter could then for example look like this:

```java
class ExpirationAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Long> {
    // No-args constructor called by Gson
    public ExpirationAdapter() { }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Long value) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Long read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        long expiration = in.nextLong();
        return System.currentTimeMillis() + (expiration * 1000L);
    }
}
```

And your `UserTokenResponse` class would look like this:

```java
class UserTokenResponse {
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    @Expose
    @JsonAdapter(ExpirationAdapter.class)
    private long accessTokenExpiresIn;

    // ...
}
```

You could even change the field type to `java.time.Instant`, which might be easier and less error-prone to work with than just a `long`, and adjust the adapter accordingly:

```java
class ExpirationAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Instant> {
    // No-args constructor called by Gson
    public ExpirationAdapter() { }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Instant value) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Instant read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        long expiration = in.nextLong();
        return Instant.now().plusSeconds(expiration);
    }
}
```

In general there are also the following other solutions, but compared to using `@JsonAdapter` they have some big drawbacks:

- Registering an adapter for the type of the field
  Not really feasible because the field has type `long` and you would then override Gson's default handling for `long` values, even for completely unrelated fields where this expiration timestamp conversion is not desired.
- Registering an adapter for the declaring type of the field
  Registering a type for `UserTokenResponse` would be possible, but you would have to manually perform the deserialization of the class, and would have to handle annotations such as `@SerializedName` manually as well. Or you would have to write a `TypeAdapterFactory` which performs the default deserialization and then afterwards adjusts the field value, but that would for example not allow changing the field type to `java.time.Instant`.

Also note that Gson does not call setter methods or constructors, it directly sets the field values. So if possible you should always provide a no-args constructor, otherwise Gson tries to create an instance without calling a constructor, which can lead to confusing errors, see [`GsonBuilder.disableJdkUnsafe()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableJdkUnsafe()) for more information.

Comment: This is great! Your answer solves my problem to the full extend. I like the extra information for only having an empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom GSON deserializer like explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502079/custom-converter-for-retrofit-2).
The last link shows how to create a custom GSON factory with a custom deserializer and how to attach it to a Retrofit instance.

Basically you would change the value of the token response inside the deserializer method.

Comment: This answer could be improved by supplying details in the post itself, in case the link supplied no longer works in the future.